# Explanation of Random-Method

Tags: java, random, methods

Could someone explain to me what exactly this method does?
I got an answer on a simulation program and this method returns a random int to use to move an "AI" in this simulation

```
protected int randomDelta() {
    int delta = 0;
    do {
        double rnd = Math.random();
        delta = rnd < 0.5d ? -1 : 1;
    } while (delta == 0);
    return delta;
}
```

Comment: Did you google "Math.random javadocs"?

Comment: It returns `-1` or `1` at random. [`Random.nextBoolean`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextBoolean--) would be more obvious.

Comment: This is a "toss coin" between -1 and 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It generates a random double, stores in `rnd`.

and for the later part... This is simpler way to translate it:

```
if(rnd < 0.5d)
    delta = -1;
else
    delta = 1;
```

Then returns `delta`.

Please have a look at conditonal operator of java as well.